# Fabric JS | Shows unwanted lines when scroll or drag any object

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, fabricjs2

I'm loading data from JSON.
Can't figure out why unwanted lines are shown on the canvas whenever I try to scroll or drag any object.

This issue only occurs when loading from JSON.
[codepen link](https://codepen.io/pramit-sawant/pen/NWbwbYO?editors=1010)

Example data is available in the codepen

```
canvas.loadFromJSON(JsonData, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
canvas.renderAll()
```

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/pramit-sawant/pen/NWbwbYO?editors=1010)
[[image: Screen Shot2]

Answer (score 0):

You have to change canvas size after loading data from json. You've added 100px to canvas size, but viewport size in json data is less that causes "dead" area that will be not updated in render.

```js
function initJsonData(JsonData){
  var size = Math.max(JsonData.width,JsonData.height) + 100;
  canvas.loadFromJSON(JsonData, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
  canvas.setWidth(size);
  canvas.setHeight(size);   
  canvas.renderAll()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function initJsonData(JsonData){
  var size = Math.max(JsonData.width,JsonData.height) + 100;
  var tempJsonData = JsonData
  delete tempJsonData .height
  delete tempJsonData .width
  canvas.loadFromJSON(tempJsonData , canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
  canvas.renderAll()
}
```

The width and height key was creating the issue. this fixed the issue